# Getting Facebook datas android

Tags: java, javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to get user's id and user's fullname, and also if possible the Facebook profile image and store it in memory to use where ever i want, here is what i tried :

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(page, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
        final ProgressBarCircular progressBarCircular = (ProgressBarCircular) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        Log.i("ADebugTag", "Value: ");


            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {

                                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
                                String a = "a";

                                Log.i("ADebugTag", "Value: " + firstName);

                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("ADebugTag", "BANANA ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.i("ADebugTag", "BOOH ");
            }
        });



    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

but "Value" in logcat is empty..

**UP**

Comment: Can you trim unrelated code to simplify the question?

Comment: What do you see when you call https://graph.prod.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=__SAME_ACCESS_TOKEN__